# Displaying a triangle pattern in with nested loops

Tags: for-loop, nested, nested-loops

The problem I am having is displaying a triangle pattern with nested loops. More specifically an upside down one. I am currently having difficulty displaying the left side of the triangle. I can see the problem to an extent but I am having trouble trying to fix it. I think the problem is I cant get the number of symbols per line to display correctly in the 2nd for loop statement without having too many numbers being displayed. Here is my code.

```
public class DisplayPatternC {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int rows = 7;
        int noOfSpaces = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 7; i <= j; j--) {
                System.out.print(i);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my output:

```
1111111
222222
33333
4444
555
66
7
```

The output I want is:

```
1111111111111
 22222222222
  333333333
   4444444
    55555
     666
      7
```

Comment: Can you please also post the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Well, just by observing the output you can determine that the number of digits per row is: (starting from the bottom) 1,3,5,7,9... Which is a formula of `2n - 1`. And you'll need to output spaces accordingly if you wish to make the triangle as specified, which goes in the pattern 0,1,2,3,4...

So the formula to obtain number of digits for each `$i` is `2 * ($rows - $i + 1) - 1`. And the number of spaces before the start of printing the digits is `$i - 1`. So go figure :)